# Python - should I use threads or processes for network activity?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am writing a python script that will upload a file to a remote FTP server when the enter key is pressed on the keyboard.

Since the enter key can be pressed randomly, multiple threads/processes could spawn concurrently.

Now should I use threading or multiprocessing to execute the upload? Which is better and why?

Comment: Since it's network(IO issue) threads should be enough.

Comment: Will there be any difference in performance?

Comment: Depends on your cpu work, but you most likely not to see the differences, also, new processes has to allocate more memory, so you better just use threading for this task.

Comment: Although, as Manuel pointed out (from the article in the link), it can be more time consuming to use mutithreading because of the GIL in python.

Comment: The GIL won't have any effect if you're dealing with network, it will be an issue with you do some calculation with your threads but that not your case. Again, threads are a good fix for you issue, you will have much less issues when trying to access shard memory(thread upload status? fail error message? common status loading bar? all of those are harder to implement with processes)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Recently I found out that multiprocessing can become an issue especially on Windows systems due to the lack of forking (as Linux does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for real parallel work you would need multiprocessing, since threads only gives an advantage in a few cases (like IO).

As already pointed out, for your IO work threads should be fine, although you should look into multiprocessing, since from my experience it isn't hard to implement either.

Also it's way easier to get a return value from `multiprocessing` than from `threads`

If you want to know why `threads` is slower for most use cases you should read this: https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/03/31/pythons-hardest-problem/

Edit: Also keep in mind that for simple tasks `threads` and `multiprocessing` actually increase the runtime, since the overhead from allocating threads/processes and higher memory usage from `multiprocessing` due to no shared memory are quite significant.